# How can I use a data-filter attribute on a listview that has multiple columns in jQuery/HTML?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I need to be able to search through a list of contacts in a jQuery Mobile site that I'm working on. It's formatted with the contacts name underneath the contacts image, and there are two columns of contacts, `ui-block-a`, and `ui-block-b`, as such:

```
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="c" class="ui-grid-b">      
        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-inset="false">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="tel:0123456789"><img src="images/personMale.png" width="100"></a>
                    <p><b>Bar, Foo</b></p>
                </li>                       
                <li>
                    <a href="tel:0123456789"><img src="images/personMale.png" width="100"></a>
                    <p><b>Santor, George</b></p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="tel:0123456789"><img src="images/personMale.png" width="100"></a>
                    <p><b>Sebastian, John</b></p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="tel:0123456789"><img src="images/personMale.png" width="100"></a>
                    <p><b>Foo, Bar </b></p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </ul>  
    </div>
```

Currently, when you search for a specific name, instead of showing only the one contact, it shows the column that it's in- either `ui-block-a` or `ui-block-b`. [Here's an example of it happening in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yTt9b/1789/). I've tried a more manual javascript approach with the `ul`s inside of `ui-block-a` and `ui-block-b`being the search target, but I basically run into the same problem. The actual project has around 10 contacts in each block/column. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by putting each contact into it's own `ui-block-a` and `ui-block-b`. Minor formatting issues, but nothing a little CSS won't fix. [Here's the updated jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/yTt9b/1790/)